# Is it possible to set puddles of water on fire?

Tags: the-sims-3

The puddles of water that can be created indoors in The Sims 3 are objects, and can be moved around when using the appropriate cheat. But I was wondering if it is possible to set them on fire. I have seen that [it is possible in The Sims 4](https://youtu.be/GzUfIHGOTGU?t=251), but I do not know if it is possible in The Sims 3. I am currently not in the position to try this out myself, which is why I am asking this here.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not set puddles of water on fire. I unintentionally tried that myself, and the result was that the fire burned everything but the puddle.